# Maintaining curves within logo

Tags: print-design, website-design, logo, design-principles, designers

I have the following logo...

[image: Put entire logo in golden ratio]

I need to adjust the "3" so that the curves used for the 3 are proportional and the same degree of arc as the other curves. Currently, the arcs within the 3 appear foreign to the overall symmetry of the other shapes.

I'm trying to explore the Golden Spiral in an effort to find the right curves for the 3.

[image]

**How should I approach altering the 3?**

Comment: What do you mean by "put it in golden ratio"?

Comment: you see this grey logo, can you explain me how to put in golden ratio in circles ?

Comment: how to make the whole logo according to the golden ratio

Comment: What I need is to make this logo out of the golden ratio circles so that every letter can be made of that circles

Comment: it's still unclear what you want. Can you add an example of a logo that has the result you're looking for?

Comment: @Luciano i added logo example

Comment: Let me see if this is right ----- You need the cures/circles in the 3 to match the other curves/circles of the logo so that all curves appear proportional and the same degree of arc? --- is that what you are after?

Comment: @Scott Yes, that i am looking for...

Comment: Marc, I've edited your question so it is hopefully much more clear to others what you are seeking. If you feel my edit was incorrect, you can always click the [edit link](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/109984/edit) under the question and re-edit or roll it back to your original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the exterior border of the 3, which is already the same diameter than the other circles.

The inside borders of this three has a different shape typology than the rest, and make an elliptical visual effect. Try to fix the inside borders of the three.

[image: sample]

Also take care about the stroke cuts. The "P" has a vertical and horizontal cut. The "3" has three different angles at the strokes endings.

[image: angles]

The "P" vertical stroke is hidden behind the "a" curved stroke.
The "3" vertical curved right stroke exceeds nearly the half of the "a" stroke width. This is optically pushing the "3" to the left.

[image: three]

What can be useful is to design the 3 alone as a circle character. Once you have the three, look for the way to assemble it to the other characters.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem for me too, Thanks, i must solve that inside border, but i don't know how .

Answer (score 3):

The question originally asked about the golden ratio, but has since been edited. So, I'll leave this as an answer since I was already working on it, and it might still be relevant.

You could use some circles whose size relates to each other in the golden ratio. Then it is possible to place the circles to act as a guide for the creation of the character.

For example, here's one way you could do it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I like the concept a great deal.

This is merely how I'd construct something similar based upon the concept.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Keeping the circles all the same and the bars the same width, and then remaining consistent with the width of the breaks is what I would aim for.

I might play with the angle for the 3 a bit. I tried a 45° triangle and that was too great an angle in my perception. And I tried a leaving the cuts in the "3" at the 0° angle - both those options seemed to be promoting the appearance of a "e" more than a "3". But there may be something between 45° and 0° that works better than the 60° which I used above.

As 0° cuts.. I guess you'd have to decide whether this shows a "3" or an "e".

[image]

---

Playing a bit more.. bringing in the bar of the 3 so it is offset by the same 15pts from the edges of the inner arc cuts seems to promote a 3 more to me. I also squared off the cap of the 3 bar, to match the square cap of the tail on the p and the a.

Then I realized I could possibly align the bar at a 60° angle from the inner points on the arc cuts.. So I tried that.

[image]

From here, I've got about 4 subtly different variations. I'd create a png of each.. wait a day or two.. then come back and look at them with *fresh eyes* to allow me to choose which direction I felt best conveyed the 3. And then adjust 
further if needed.

Comment: Love this answer! Awesome tutorial as well! +1

Comment: Careful with the devil's trident shape 

Comment: You see whatever it is you see. That would have *never* entered my mind. I don't think in those terms.

Comment: I am not criticizing your work, it is simple optical perception. What answer would there be if the client has the same perception?

Comment: My clients are generally practical and far more interested in *business and sales* than they are in underlying, remote, subtle, random, religious overtones. `:)`

Comment: Lucky you :-) Anyway i was not talking about your clients, for the simple reason I don't know them. Generally speaking, if there is a presentation in front of three or four people, as it usually is, and one of them thinks the logo looks like a shark riding a monkey, the answer should be: -You see whatever it is you see. That would have never entered my mind. I don't think in those terms.-?

Comment: Yes. I'd have no problem saying that to a client. Often what someone sees out of random shapes tells you much more about the individual than your artwork. There's no blanket answer here.